# aligning face image and merge in python cv2

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have a bunch of face image dataset (taken from http://vision.ucsd.edu/content/yale-face-database ) that I basically want to turn into a gif of the scramble suit from the movie scanner darkly ( http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-tRLWSOqh84Y/VSb_cF7sOoI/AAAAAAAAAWI/3XqT6d_exso/s1600/scramble%2Bsuit%2B2.gif ).
So far, I am able to take the images and cut them into face "pieces" in python in bulk.
The next step I am unable to do is to "align" these faces so that all the pieces form a face when they are merged or put back together.
Im also unsure how to merge or put them back together.
Once i have a bunch of images of randomly pieced together images, i am able to create the gif myself.

here is the code i have so far of taking the images, converting them to jpg and cutting them into necessary pieces (which was taken from here https://leslietj.github.io/2020/06/30/Automatic-Face-Crop-Using-Dlib/ ):

```
import sys
import dlib
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import math
from PIL import Image
import os

def arc_points(point1, point2, num_of_points):
    points = []
    center_x = (point1[0] + point2[0])/2
    center_y = (point1[1] + point2[1])/2
    radius = abs((point1[0] - point2[0])/2)
    for i in range(num_of_points):
        if i == 0:
            continue
    
        point = []
        x = center_x + radius * math.cos(math.pi + i * math.pi / num_of_points)
        y = center_y + radius * math.sin(math.pi + i * math.pi / num_of_points)
        point.append(x)
        point.append(y)
        
        points.append(point)
    
    return points


def get_landmarks(img,mode=1):
    dets = detector(img, 1)
    landmarks = np.zeros((34, 2))
    for k, d in enumerate(dets):
        shape = predictor(img, d)

        #quarter face (#1)
        if mode == 1:
            landmarks[0]= (shape.part(0).x, shape.part(0).y)
            landmarks[1] = (shape.part(1).x, shape.part(1).y)
            landmarks[2] = (shape.part(2).x, shape.part(2).y)
            landmarks[3] = (shape.part(30).x, shape.part(30).y)
            landmarks[4] = (shape.part(29).x, shape.part(29).y)
            landmarks[5] = (shape.part(28).x, shape.part(28).y)
            point1 = [shape.part(0).x, shape.part(0).y]
            point2 = [shape.part(28).x, shape.part(28).y]
            points = arc_points(point1, point2, 29)
            for i in range(len(points)):
                landmarks[33 - i] = (points[i][0], points[i][1])
        

        #half face (#2)

        if mode == 2:
            landmarks[0] = (shape.part(0).x, shape.part(0).y)
            landmarks[1] = (shape.part(1).x, shape.part(1).y)
            landmarks[2] = (shape.part(2).x, shape.part(2).y)
            landmarks[3] = (shape.part(14).x, shape.part(14).y)
            landmarks[4] = (shape.part(15).x, shape.part(15).y)
            landmarks[5] = (shape.part(16).x, shape.part(16).y)
            point1 = [shape.part(0).x, shape.part(0).y]
            point2 = [shape.part(16).x, shape.part(16).y]
            points = arc_points(point1, point2, 29)
            #print(points)
            for i in range(len(points)):
                #print(33-i)
                landmarks[33 - i] = (points[i][0], points[i][1])
        
        if mode == 3:
            #3/4 face (#3)
            for i in range(9):
                landmarks[i] = (shape.part(i).x, shape.part(i).y)
            landmarks[9] = (shape.part(31).x, shape.part(31).y)
            
            landmarks[10] = (shape.part(14).x, shape.part(14).y)
            landmarks[11] = (shape.part(15).x, shape.part(15).y)
            landmarks[12] = (shape.part(16).x, shape.part(16).y)
            point1 = [shape.part(0).x, shape.part(0).y]
            point2 = [shape.part(16).x, shape.part(16).y]
            points = arc_points(point1, point2, 22)
            for i in range(len(points)):
                landmarks[33 - i] = (points[i][0], points[i][1])
        #full face (#4)
        if mode == 4:
            for i in range(17):
                landmarks[i] = (shape.part(i).x, shape.part(i).y)
            point1 = [shape.part(0).x, shape.part(0).y]
            point2 = [shape.part(16).x, shape.part(16).y]
            points = arc_points(point1, point2, 18)
            for i in range(len(points)):
                landmarks[33 - i] = (points[i][0], points[i][1])
        

    return landmarks


def inside(X,Y,Region): 
    j=len(Region)-1
    flag=False
    for i in range(len(Region)):
        if (Region[i][1]<Y and Region[j][1]>=Y or Region[j][1]<Y and Region[i][1]>=Y):  
            if (Region[i][0] + (Y - Region[i][1]) / (Region[j][1] - Region[i][1]) * (Region[j][0] - Region[i][0]) < X):
                flag =not flag
        j=i
    return flag

count=0
files = os.listdir('yalefaces')
for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith('glasses') or filename.endswith('happy') or filename.endswith('noglasses') or filename.endswith('normal'):
        path = os.path.join('yalefaces',filename)

  
        # importing the image 
        im = Image.open(path)

      
        # converting to jpg
        rgb_im = im.convert("RGB")
      
        # exporting the image
        rgb_im.save('temp.jpg')

        count+=1


        path = 'temp.jpg'
        for im in range(1,5):
            #path = 'subject01.jpg'
            detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() 
        # the .dat file can be downloaded following this link:
        # https://sourceforge.net/projects/dclib/files/dlib/v18.10/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2/download
            predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
            img = io.imread(path)

            region = get_landmarks(img,mode=im)
            shape = list(img.shape) 
            cropped_img = img.copy()
            for i in range(shape[0]):
                for j in range(shape[1]):
                    if not inside(j, i, region):
                        #print(img[0])
                        cropped_img[i, j] = (img[0,0][0], img[0,0][1], img[0,0][2]) # the RGB values of the background


            cropped_img = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            cv2.imwrite(str(count).zfill(3)+'-'+str(im).zfill(2)+'.jpg', cropped_img)
```

Comment: don't split them up first. align them first. then you can compose multiple faces into pieces of each.

Comment: yes, i found this https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/05/22/face-alignment-with-opencv-and-python/ that does face alignment. after alignment i can cut them up but now the other question of putting them back together remains. i tried to do a cv2.add() but all it did is just make the image super white

Comment: perhaps you'll want to review [ask] and [mre]. you've posted a lot of code. once you've broken "the problem" into subtasks, you'll know what to look for, or what to ask for, without expecting people to sift through everything at once. -- if you have a question about `cv.add()` you can search for similar questions on that, or ask that specifically, but not in a comment.

Comment: apologies. i solved the issue myself after some research. i will post my solution shortly

Answer (score 0):

since this is several steps of pre-processing:

1. align faces using this script https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/05/22/face-alignment-with-opencv-and-python/
2. cut up the faces and put them together. as mentioned before, i was doing a cv2.add which is not what i want. i actually want the layers to stack up and if there is anything underneath, ignore it. cv2.add doesnt do this so i had to make my own. so if i had two layers and i want to stack them up so that the first layer on top is the one that takes priority and the bottom layer is ignored if there is anything above it.

```
def reduction(layer1,layer2):
    for i in range(0,layer1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,layer1.shape[1]):
            pixel1 = layer1.item(i, j)
            pixel2 = layer2.item(i, j)
            if layer2[i,j] != 255:
                layer1[i,j]=255
    return layer1

layer2 = reduction(layer2,layer1)

for i in range(0,layer1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,layer1.shape[1]):
        pixel = layer2[i,j]
        if pixel != 255:
            layer1[i,j]=layer2[i,j]
```

and thats it. i didnt realize images are just numpy arrays so i can just manipulate the arrays directly.